# jQuery Auto complete plugin, multiple selection overrides previous selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am utilizing the [jQuery Auto Complete Plugin](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) in a view for a text field. Single selection works perfectly.

I am incorporating multiple select, but for some reason if I select multiple values, the previous selection gets overridden.

I am following the examples as on the [jQuery Plugin Tutorials](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote).

```
 $("#ServiceEntryFilter_System").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: serviceentrySystemURL, type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                minLength: 0,
                data: { searchText: extractLast(request.term), maxResult: 100, instrumenttype: userroleid },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { value: item }
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
        focus: function () {
            // prevent value inserted on focus
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var terms = split(this.value);

            // remove the current input

            terms.pop();

            // add the selected item

            terms.push(ui.item.value);

            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end

            terms.push("");

            this.value = terms.join(", ");

            return false;


        }
    });

    function split(val) {

        return val.split(/,\s*/);

    }

    function extractLast(term) {

        return split(term).pop();

    }


[HttpPost]
public JsonResult FindSystem(string searchText, int maxResult, string instrumenttype)
{
    int UserRoleID = AccessHelper.GetUserRoleID(User.Identity.Name);
    var result = RunLog.Domain.Lists.GlobalList.GetInstrumentSystem(searchText, maxResult, instrumenttype);

    return Json(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you are looking for, but the select event is not what you want. It seems to be overwriting the value AFTER you run the function.

I tried this, and it seemed to add values to the array: (I just changed it to focus)

```
            focus: function(event, ui){
            var terms = this.value.split(", ");

            // remove the current input

            terms.pop();

            // add the selected item

            terms.push(ui.item.value);

            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end

            terms.push("");

            this.value = terms.join(", ");

            return false;


        }
```